# How to run api and website with ssl and on same domain name

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, https, lets-encrypt

I have the following website nepherius.xyz, I want to run a regular domain and an API using the same name something like:

https://nepherius.xyz - this would be the regular webpage
https://nepherius.xyz:8433 - this would be the api

Current nginx.conf, most of it generated by certbot from letsencrypt

```
server {

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name nepherius.xyz www.nepherius.xyz_;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8433;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nepherius.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nepherius.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = nepherius.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name nepherius.xyz www.nepherius.xyz_;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.nepherius.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    server_name www.nepherius.xyz;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Now the API works fine but not the regular site, if I remove

```
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8433;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

then regular site works but API doesn't. So how would I make both work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating two servers, for example:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.nepherius.xyz;
    ...
}

server {
    listen       8433;
    server_name  www.nepherius.xyz;
    ...
}
```

These will help to use your domain in different ports.